# DataFrame Selection Within Date Ranges Returns without Rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am following the commonly recommended process on SO for consolidating a DataFrame to only a sample selection that I plan on using for my analysis, but somewhere in the process of using `pd.date_range` and the selection between the dates, the data goes missing with the column headers as the only data that exists.

Here are my variables:

```
custom_date_start = '2018-01-01'

custom_date_end= '2018-10-31'

sheet_date = 'date'

df_clean # raw data table
```

Table briefly described:

```
display(df_clean.head(3))
display(df_clean.tail(3))

# output

date    b_clicks    b_leads b_sals
2   1/1/2018    72  6   5
3   1/2/2018    232 9   7
4   1/3/2018    255 23  17
date    b_clicks    b_leads b_sals
729 12/29/2019          
730 12/30/2019          
731 12/31/2019
```

Sample selection:

```
date_range = pd.date_range(custom_date_start, custom_date_end)

print(date_range)

display(df_clean.head(1))
display(df_clean.tail(1))

df_clean_test = df_clean[(df_clean[sheet_date] > custom_date_start) & (df_clean[sheet_date] <= custom_date_end)]

display(df_clean_test.head(1))
display(df_clean_test.tail(1))

# output

DatetimeIndex(['2018-01-01', '2018-01-02', '2018-01-03', '2018-01-04',
               '2018-01-05', '2018-01-06', '2018-01-07', '2018-01-08',
               '2018-01-09', '2018-01-10',
               ...
               '2018-10-22', '2018-10-23', '2018-10-24', '2018-10-25',
               '2018-10-26', '2018-10-27', '2018-10-28', '2018-10-29',
               '2018-10-30', '2018-10-31'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=304, freq='D')
date    b_clicks    b_leads b_sals # df_clean
2   1/1/2018    72  6   5
date    b_clicks    b_leads b_sals # df_clean
731 12/31/2019          
date    b_clicks    b_leads b_sals # df_clean_test
date    b_clicks    b_leads b_sals # df_clean_test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is correct but the problem is in comparison.

Consider this example,

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': {0: '26/1/2016 ', 1: '27/1/2016 '}})
df1
```

Output:

```
      Date
0   26/1/2016
1   27/1/2016
```

Other dataframe,

```
date_range = pd.date_range('2016-01-26', '2016-01-27')
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': date_range})
df2
```

Output:

```
    Date
0   2016-01-26
1   2016-01-27
```

Let's compare dates which are in different format,

```
print(df2['Date'] == df1['Date'])
```

Output:

```
0    False
1    False
Name: Date, dtype: bool
```

Now, correct the format of `Date` of df1,

```
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'])
df1
```

Output:

```
       Date
0   2016-01-26
1   2016-01-27
```

Let's compare the dates of two dataframes again,

```
print(df1['Date'] == df2['Date'])
```

Output:

```
0    True
1    True
Name: Date, dtype: bool
```

In your example, `date` in `df_clean` is not in correct format so that's why in comparison, all values are false and no rows are returned.